# Storing objects into a HashMap

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, hashmap, key-value

I have an XML which I'm converting to a java object using JAXB in the following way:

```
package IRCurves;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class XmlToObject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("InterestRates_JPY_20160426.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(InterestRateCurve.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            InterestRateCurve ir= (InterestRateCurve) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

            System.out.println(ir.getEffectiveasof()+" "+ir.getCurrency()+" "+ir.getBaddayconvention());
            System.out.println("Deposits:");
            List<Deposits> list=ir.getDeposits();
            for(Deposits ans:list) {
                System.out.println(ans.getDaycountconvention()+" "+ans.getSnaptime()+" "+ans.getSpotdate());
                System.out.println("Calenders:");
                List<Calenders> list1=ans.getCalenders();
                for(Calenders c:list1)
                    System.out.println(c.getCalender());
                System.out.println("Curvepoint:");
                List<Curvepoint> list2=ans.getCurvepoint();
                for(Curvepoint curve:list2)
                    System.out.println(curve.getTenor()+" "+curve.getMaturitydate()+" "+curve.getParrate());
            }
            System.out.println("Swaps:");
            List<Swaps> list3=ir.getSwaps();
            for(Swaps swap:list3) {
                System.out.println(swap.getFixeddaycountconvention()+" "+swap.getFloatingdaycountconvention()+" "+swap.getFixedpaymentfrequency()+" "+swap.getFloatingpaymentfrequency()+" "+swap.getSnaptime()+" "+swap.getSpotdate());
            /*System.out.println("Calenders:");  
            List<Calenders> list1=swap.getCalenders();
            for(Calenders c:list1)  
                System.out.println(c.getCalender());*/
                System.out.println("Curvepoint:");
                List<Curvepoint> list2=swap.getCurvepoint();
                for(Curvepoint curve:list2)
                    System.out.println(curve.getTenor()+" "+curve.getMaturitydate()+" "+curve.getParrate());
            }
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to store this into a Hash Map of the form `HashMap<"Deposits_1M", 2016-06-29 -0.00029)`, where `1M` is the value we get by doing `curve.getTenor()` and `2016-06-29` is one of the value we get by doing `curve.getMaturitydate()` & `-.00029` we get by doing `curve.getParrate()`. so, basically I want the value we get from each iteration of `for(Curvepoint curve:list2)` for `getTenor()` to be as key along with the string `"Deposits"`, and the value we get from `curve.getMaturitydate(`) and `curve.getParrate()` to be as the value of one hash map entry.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java collections Maps (including HashMap) are parametric, so you need to include the key and value types in the declaration:

```
Map<String,String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then to create an entry, you use Map.put, so in your case I think this would be:

```
resultsMap.put(curve.getTenor(), curve.getMaturitydate()+" "+curve.getParrate())
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a structure to have 1 key map to multiple values?

```
HashMap<String,List<Integer> results = new HashMap<String,List<Integer>();
// Does Key already exist?
List<Integer> temp = results.get(curve.getTenor());

       if(temp != null){

               //if it does add to object
               temp.add(curve.getMaturitydate());
               temp.add(curve.getParrate());


       }else{
           // if not make object and put in has map
       List<Integer> nn = new ArrayList<Integer>();

       nn.add(curve.getMaturitydate());
       nn.add(curve.getParrate());
       userList.put(curve.getTenor(), nn);

           }
```

Then in your struct all values would be stored in ArrayList Position 0-1.
If you didn't want to split strings or store them as a concat. Also now if values change and store multiple answers. every 2 array indexes are a pair of values.